# Get a list of orders by excluding the recents one in the same category?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of the following structure (simplified):

Table orders

```
id
created
name
executed
category_id
```

I need a list of n orders from distinct categories (if `n` is 5, I should have at most 5 different categories, and never two same categories). I successfully done this one using the following request :

```
SELECT   name 
FROM     orders 
WHERE    executed IS NULL 
GROUP BY category_id LIMIT 5;
```

But I'd need to exclude the categories that has already been processed less than an hour ago.

For that, I was able to do the following query :

```
SELECT   name, category_id 
FROM     orders 
WHERE    executed IS NULL 
AND      category_id NOT IN (SELECT   category_id 
                             FROM     orders 
                             WHERE    executed > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) 
                             GROUP BY category_id) 
GROUP BY category_id 
LIMIT 5;
```

But I was wondering if there was a faster way to get the results.

I've made an [SQLFiddle to show my example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d663), but I find it quite slow and I was not able to get a successful result from them.

Here's an alternative version with a LEFT JOIN I tried but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT  u1.some, u1.columns
    FROM  orders AS u1
    LEFT JOIN  orders AS u2  ON u1.category_id = u2.category_id
      AND  u2.executed > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND)
    WHERE  u1.created < (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND)
      AND  (u1.executed IS NULL
              OR  u1.executed < (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
           )
      AND  u2.category_id IS NOT NULL
      AND  u1.category_id NOT IN u2.category_id
    LIMIT  10;
```

Comment: `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` can perform very poorly; turn it into a `LEFT JOIN`.  Or `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * ... )`

Comment: I've tested with more entries, and indeed, it's beginning to get a bit slow (my request). I've tried yours but can not make it work (mostly using the left join). I've updated my question to include a left join. I suspect it's around the u1.category_id NOT IN u2.category_id but I don't know what to change. Could you help me @RickJames ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the query by adding an index as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `orders` ADD KEY ix_executed(executed,category_id);
```

Create table `orders` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `executed` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `category_id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_executed` (`executed`,`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Rest of your query seems good to me.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mentionned it on sqlfiddle nor on the question but there is already a few indexes on that table : executed, category_id, created and id. But I didn't add an index on executed+category_id at the same time. Does it changes much?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  u1.some, u1.columns
    FROM       orders AS u1
    LEFT JOIN  orders AS u2  ON u1.category_id = u2.category_id
    WHERE  u1.created  < (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND)
      AND  u2.executed > (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND)
      AND  (u1.executed IS NULL
              OR  u1.executed < (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
           )
      AND  u2.category_id IS NULL
    LIMIT  10;
```

`ON` should include only the condition(s) that tie the two tables together.

`LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` is how to say "it's in the left table, but not the right".

(I don't know if the rest of the `WHERE` is what you needed; I just copied your stuff.)

Unless you don't care about which 10, you need an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: What will differ from settings the clause in the `on` or the `where`? I've made some tests with settings the where on the `on` and the results where apparently coherent?

Comment: Clarity.  That is, as a _reader_, I like the `ON` to reflect how the tables are related, and the `WHERE` to do the filtering.  In _most, but not all_ cases, the effect is identical, whether a condition is in the `ON` or in the `WHERE`.  `LEFT JOIN` is where it matters.  Do `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS;` to see how the statement is executed.